# Geany equivalent of ALT + 5 (minimize blocks) in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, folding, geany

In Notepad++ I can use the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to minimize all the first child blocks (the little boxes with +/-). Does Geany have a way to do this?

If not, is there a plugin that will let me create this functionality?

Comment: just a note that **Alt+1** thru **Alt+8** minimze blocks in Notepad++, so if you mention "1st child blocks", generally they get collapsed by **Alt+8**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Geany, only three folding keyboard shortcuts are assignable:

[image]

(Maybe you can consider returning to good old Notepad++ :)

Comment: I would, but I don't want to run it through Wine since that brings its own intricacies. Geany seems to have everything of N++ except sub-folding - there's even a N++ color scheme!

Comment: OK, then simply put, the answer is that folding functionality of sublevels cannot be easily achieved in Geany.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  Although if you could point me in the right direction of the hard way to implement this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please see [the Geany wishlist](http://www.geany.org/Support/PluginWishlist) - the idea is there already, 6th from the top. Obviously you are not the only one who is missing it so there is a good chance it will be added soon. Regarding your own implementation, you can first check [Geany sources](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases#source) and tell how do you feel about implementing anything in there.

Comment: Quick update. I've found that the "Numbered Bookmarks" geany plugin is the best alternative... it allows you to save the folding status for your files.